# use of a bash command to prefix a header to stdout?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I just saw an example on a site which piped the output of an awk command to the following command:

```
(echo "this is a header";cat -)
```

This effectively adds the header string at the top of the output..it seems like - represents stdout there. What is this construct though? With a parenthesis, and then cat -? How does this work, this seems quite useful but it's the first time I see it..

Comment: `-` after `cat` is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of parentheses here is a "Grouping Construct" -- see the details in the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

A similar construct uses braces:

```
{ echo "this is a header"; cat -; }
```

This is different syntax that requires whitespace around the braces and the trailing semi-colon.

The difference between using braces and parentheses is this: command list in braces runs in your *current* shell, command list in parentheses runs in a *subshell*. This is important if you want the command list to alter your environment -- when a subshell exits, environment changes will be lost.

Answer (score 8):

`-` often can be use to denote `stdin` in command line options that accept a file name argument. Note that the effect of `cat -` is the same as plain `cat`, i.e. both versions read `stdin` anyway.

The parenthesis cause the shell to run the commands in a [sub-shell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html). `(...)` is essentially `bash -c '...'` if the shell is `bash`. It is done because in `xyz | echo "..."; cat` the output of `xyz` would be piped into `echo` and lost.